# Handling multiple checkboxes in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to click on multiple checkboxes in my react component and to handle which checkboxes are checked. i want to confirm when click on 'Verify' that name and address are checked by passing the checked state of each checkbox. can someone help me in that?

```
export class Form extends React.Component<FormProps, {
  ...,
  isChecked?: boolean
}> {

  constructor(props: FormProps) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      ...,
      isChecked:false
    };
    private checkField = () => {
    console.log('state is '+this.state.isChecked) 
     }
  }
  }
render() {
  return<Fragment>   
 <Input name="Name" required={true} handleChecked={(isChecked: boolean) => this.setState({isChecked})} />
 <Input name="Address" required={true} handleChecked={(isChecked: boolean) => this.setState({isChecked})} />
 <Input name="Birthdate" />
<div onClick={this.checkField}> Verify</div>
</Fragment>
  }
}

export function Input(props: React.PropsWithChildren<{name: string, required?: boolean, handleChecked?: (checked: boolean) => void}>) {
 
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false)
  
  return <Fragment>
    <div>
      {props.name}
      <label htmlFor={props.name}>Selection {props.required ? '(Required)': ''}</label>
      <input 
        id={props.name} 
        type='checkbox'
        name={props.name}
        checked={isChecked}
        onChange={
          setIsChecked(!isChecked)
          if(props.handleChecked) {
            props.handleChecked(!isChecked);
            }
          }
        }/>
    </div>
  </Fragment>;
}
```

Comment: Your parent component (the one that is using  multiple `<Input>`s) needs to have a separate state for each checked value.

Comment: could you post the code in your parent component as well as show what problem you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment section, you need to create separate state for name and address checkbox value and pass it to the `<Input>` component.

```
class Wrapper extends Component {
  state = {
   isNameChecked: false,
   isAddressChecked: false,
  }

  render() {
   <Input
     name="Name"
     required={true}
     handleChecked={(isNameChecked: boolean) => this.setState({ isNameChecked })}
     isChecked={this.state.isNameChecked}
   />

   <Input
     name="Address"
     required={true}
     handleChecked={(isAddressChecked: boolean) => this.setState({ isAddressChecked })}
     isChecked={this.state.isAddressChecked}
   />

   <Input name="Birthdate" />
  }
}
```

```
export function Input(props: React.PropsWithChildren<{
 name: string,
 required?: boolean,
 handleChecked?: (checked: boolean) => void,
 isChecked: boolean,
}>) {
  return (
   <div>
      {props.name}
      <label htmlFor={props.name}>Selection {props.required ? '(Required)': ''}</label>
      <input 
        id={props.name} 
        type='checkbox'
        name={props.name}
        checked={isChecked}
        onChange={
          if (props.handleChecked) {
              props.handleChecked(!isChecked);
          }
        }
     }/>
    </div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can go about this in a few different ways..
I would suggest something like this:

```
interface State = {
  name: boolean;
  address: boolean;
}

class Wrapper extends Component {
  state: Readonly<State> = {
    name: false,
    address: false,
  }

  handleChecked = e => {
     setState({
       [e.target.name]: e.target.checked
     })
  }

  render() {
    <Input
      name="name"
      required
      handleChecked={handleChecked}
    />
    <Input
      name="address"
      required
      handleChecked={handleChecked}
    />
  }
}

function Child({ 
  name,
  handleChecked
}: { 
  name: string;
  handleChecked: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
}) {
  return (
     <input 
        ...
        type='checkbox'
        name={name}
        onChange={handleChecked}
     />
  )
}
```

Then you could handle things based on the parent's state.
i.e. -

```js
class Wrapper extends Component {
  ...

  foo = () => {
    if (state.name && state.email) {
       // do whatever..
    }
  }

  ...
}
```